# How to properly use extends instances in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, assertion, union-types

I use TypeScript, but there is still a lot of confusion.

I created an instance like this:

```js
interface Product {
  type: 'free'|'pay';
  price?: number;
}
```

The reason I set price as an optional property is because I want to make it a valid property only when the type is 'pay'.

Because of that, I want to create an interface like this:

```js
interface Product {
  type: 'free'|'pay';
}

interface PayProduct extends Product {
  type: 'pay';
  price: number;
}
```

And I want to use it like this.

```js
const loggingPrice = (product: Product) => {
  if (product.type !== 'pay') return;
  // product is definitely PayProduct.
  const { price } = product;
  console.log(price);
}
```

But, of course, it returns an error like this:
`TS2339: Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Product'.`

That's why I use type assertion.

```js
interface Product {
  type: 'free'|'pay';
}

interface PayProduct extends Product {
  type: 'pay';
  price: number;
}

const loggingPrice = (product: Product) => {
  if (product.type !== 'pay') return;
  // product is definitely PayProduct.
  const { price } = product as PayProduct;
  console.log(price);
}
```

I can't think of another way.

I think this is a bad way.
I really don't like type assertions. (I feel like I'm lying to type checkers.)

What is the best way to use these defined interfaces?

I apologize for my poor English skills. (I rely on automatic translation.)
But I am very curious if there is a way to use these interfaces properly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "I apologize for my poor English skills"... Don't. It was a well asked question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't extend. Create a discriminated union of the two types instead. Now it's one or the other (without the possibility of being just a base-interface instance). The test `product.type !== 'pay'` will narrow correctly.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

```
interface PayProduct {
  type: 'pay';
  price: number;
}

interface FreeProduct {
  type: 'free';
}

type Product = PayProduct | FreeProduct;

const loggingPrice = (product: Product) => {
  if (product.type !== 'pay') return;
  // product is definitely PayProduct.
  const { price } = product;
  console.log(price);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ6qgewCYCuCYyA3gLABQyNyYGADhAFzIDkDmbA3FbcgyjAkrEAQC2AI2i9KAXypVQkWIhQAxKBAjZ8REhWq16TVmxhaIPKgspUTKXYWLIAvGkxP9yAD7JN2l7EslQIOCAAziQANjgA5nGgcdjCKO4AFIJ6xKxBYACUbgB8ZHy0wDDImbjOYAB0DsgAhK7uHFyFWmAEUCCy-AD0AwI13sARyHgQMKDAkNEYHlijxHVlNGGRBiOpyHJuI9lg-bSbETjREHWxcdWp+bJyQA)

Comment: You shared the documentation so I was able to trust this method.
Thank you very much.